# period when citing a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

> "The birds flew." is the sentence I wrote last night.

Should you put a dot or not?

What about:

> "The beautiful flowers are there." is the last thing I wrote.

?

Comment: You should not use the period.

Comment: I'm not speaking from authority, but I think the period looks terrible and I never include it unless it comes at the end of a sentence anyway.

Comment: Or this? [Should I put commas and periods before the ending quotation mark?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235722/should-i-put-commas-and-periods-before-the-ending-quotation-mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer has exceptions in certain contexts, but should be accurate as a general rule.

Don't include the period within a mid-sentence quote if the quote is *not* at the end of the sentence. For example, you can use a period in the quote of this sentence:

> The sentence I wrote last night was "The birds flew."

If you are quoting a single sentence, and the quote is not at the end of the sentence, you will often replace the period with a comma:

> "The birds flew," I wrote last night.

However, when the quotation is the direct subject of the sentence, you will omit the period entirely.

> "The birds flew" is the sentence I wrote last night.

If you are writing a longer quotation, it is what is called a *blockquote*.  In a blockquote, you include all original punctuation.  Blockquotes are not contained within other sentences.

> Abraham Lincoln gave this speech on November 19, 1863.
>
> "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
>
> "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.
>
> "But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us -- that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion -- that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom -- and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth."

Note that this block quote spans several paragraphs, and that each of these paragraphs has an opening quotation mark, but only the last one has a closing quotation mark.  This is a style-guide related syntax, but may vary with other style-guides.